# why does sum from multiIndex dataframe drop target column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have following multi index dataframe:

```
offset A B C
0      0 0 100
         1 200
         2 300
         3 400
       1 0 10
         1 20
         2 30
         3 40
...
```

To group `A` and sum values of `C`, I execute:

```
df.droplevel('B').sum(level = [0, 1], axis = 0)
```

whose exepcted output must be:

```
offset A C
0      0 1000
0      1 100
...
```

However, the output is (column `C` is discarded):

```
offset A
0      0
       1
1      0
       1
...
```

Is there something wrong to get expected output (why is column `C` discarded)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C` is also in your Multiindex, there is no `sum` happening at all.
If you would change your code to `df.droplevel('B').sum(level = [0, 1, 2], axis = 0)` you would see column `C`, it is not discarded.

Running your code is returning a warning for me:

> FutureWarning: Using the level keyword in DataFrame and Series aggregations is deprecated
> and will be removed in a future version.
> Use groupby instead. df.sum(level=1) should use df.groupby(level=1).sum()

You want to do it like this for example:

```
res = df.reset_index(level=-1).groupby(level=[0,1]).sum()
print(res)

             C
offset A      
0      0  1000
       1   100
```

`C` is no index at the moment.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So is the point here that column `C` must be separated from the multi index before `sum()`?

Comment: to my knowledge: yes.